# Ruby: Method Alias: Child - Parent Class

Tags: ruby, class, methods, parent-child, alias

I have the following:

```
class Parent
  def A
    return 'A'
  end
  def B
    return 'B'
  end
end

class Child < Parent
  def A
    super
    return 'Child.A'
  end
  def B
    super
    return 'Child.B'
  end
end
```

When I do:
    p Child.A
    ==> Child.A

And then I added this below the above code.

```
class Child < Parent
  alias method_of_child_A A
  def A
    method_of_child_A
  end
end
```

When I do

```
p Child.A
=> A
```

It returns me 'A', instead of 'Child.A'. And I'm looking for Child.A.
And I'd like the syntax to be able to do the following also.

```
Class GrandChild < Child
  alias method_of_GrandChild_A A #if Grandchild.A doesn't exist, 
                                 #it will alias Child.A instead.
                                 #Which what alias does basically.
  def A
    method_of_GrandChild_A
  end
end
```

So when I do:
    p GrandChild.A
    => Child.A

I'm not too familiar with the alias function, so could someone enlighten me? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your code already works as you would expect:

```
require 'pry'
class Parent
  def A; 'A'; end
  def B; 'B'; end
end

class Child < Parent
  def A; 'Child.A'; end
  def B; 'Child.B'; end
end

class Child < Parent
  alias method_of_child_A A
  def A
    method_of_child_A
  end
end

p Child.new.A #=> "Child.A"
```

My edits were cosmetic to make the code slightly shorter.

Comment: what if I would like the definition to have super?

Comment: You can just leave it in there, it wasn't doing anything in the example code so I just pulled it out. I wouldn't format the production code with one-line def's - just trying to be terse.